# Faithfully flat etale morphism from strictly Henselian ring (from Etale Cohomology and the Weil Conjecture by Freitag/Kiehl)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

I have question about a statement found in Etale Cohomology and the Weil Conjecture by Freitag, Kiehl at the end of page 15.
It starts with the *Remark 1.18* : Let $A$ be a strictly Henselian ring (i.e. Henselian + residue class field separably algebraically closed). Then every *local-etale* homomorphism $A \to B$ is an isomorphism.

Assume 1.18 as black box (references where its proof can be found are welcome). Additionally, *local-etale* map is defined on page 8; Def 1.4:

A map $A \to B$ of local rings is local-etale iff it is
a) flat + unramified
b)finitely generated local morphism; a fglm is defined on page 7: its a morphism where $B$ arise as a *localization* of a finitely generated $A$-algebra.

Now we come to my question: It is clamed at the end of page 15 comming immediately after quoted remark 1.18 that

For every faithfully flat etale homomorphism $\phi: A \to B$ of a strictly Henselian ring $A$ into a finitely generated $A$-algebra $B$ there exist a right inverse; that is a map $\psi: B \to A$ with $\psi \circ \phi= id_A$.

**Question:** Wht this is true and in particular where is faithfully flatness exploited?

My idea was to find an appropriate localization $B_L$ such that the composition $A \to B \to B_L$ is local-etale and then use 1.18. Modulo explicite finding of such localization I not use that the morphsims is faithfully flat. Therefore Im confused who it is neccessary.
And ... in the book Rmk is mentioned without a reference. Where its proof can be found?

Comment: If $B$ is obtained from $A$ by inverting one or more elements of the maximal ideal then the map will be flat but not faithfully flat and won't have an inverse.

Comment: yes thats a good special case where it would fail if we discard faithfully-flatness,right. Do you see a way to give a proof which explicitely exploits it?

Comment: Reference for 1.18: Raynaud, Anneaux locaux henseliens, VII, \S 3, Prop. 3.

Comment: I would use faithful flatness to ensure there is a point of $B$ lying over the maximal ideal of $A$, and then localize $B$ at that point.

Comment: right, here we need surjectivity on Spec map, thats the crucial ingredient, thanks!